# Discrepancy between question creation time and "last seen"

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page, last-seen

The question I'm referring to is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23784436/how-to-open-a-java-file.

The question was created **11 minutes ago**:

[image: asked]

and [the user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3659863/user3659863) was last seen **26 minutes ago**.

[image: seen]

Is this good ol' caching or is it a bug?

Comment: There is a 30 minute window on actualization of the *last seen* time.

Comment: The last seen time isn't updated in real time. Don't assume there is a correlation. :-)

Comment: Ok, can someone post an answer then and I'll accept! :-)

Comment: You yourself are marked as having been seen 8 minutes ago, yet the question is only 5 minutes old.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sure, but I'm descended from unicorns so I don't really count.

Comment: See [Timestamp on question is later than Profile's Seen, must be some time traveller or ninja](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70232)

Comment: I had exactly the same question. This question is asked 1 hour ago (as we speak) and the user is last seen 2 hours ago. Quiet strange :P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As explained in the comments and in [Timestamp on question is later than Profile's Seen, must be some time traveller or ninja](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70232/timestamp-on-question-is-later-than-profiles-seen-must-be-some-time-traveller), the "last seen" time is not a real-time value so these apparent discrepancies can occur.

Comment: Last seen time while checking profile always shows wrong. Right now I am online but it says 4 mins ago for me.