# Question asked by someone last seen a month earlier?

Tags: support, timestamps, last-seen

I answered a [question that was posted 4 days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18376061/317266) and while looking at the OP "last seen" time to see if he possibly could have read my answer, I notice that he is supposed not having used SO for quite a whole month before the question post.

[image: time traveller]

I did searched the archives and found that there could be "30 minutes" window on the accuracy of the "last seen" value as told in [that answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255666/discrepancy-between-question-creation-time-and-last-seen) and [its reference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70232/timestamp-on-question-is-later-than-profiles-seen-must-be-some-time-traveller), but a month is some magnitude orders bigger. That's why I prefer ask for that possible bug.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That question was posted 1 year and 4 days ago; not 4 days ago.

It happens to us all :)

Comment: Wait, it's 2014? ... where did this last decade go?

Comment: This is why relative dates were a genius innovation. It happens to me with distressing frequency.

Comment: Gosh, I need some more caffeine today :( and I think I will wipe that non-question

Comment: Even with more caffeine, I still wonder then why that 1 year old question was in my mailbox notifications this weekend, it seems not having recent modification. o_O

Comment: @Stijn: yes it is my answer. But I would not have seen the question if it did not have been sent in my tag mail digest. Weird.

Comment: @Seki I wonder if it's one of the methods the [Community](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) user uses to "poke old unanswered questions every hour so they get some attention"?

Comment: No, Community bumping does not show up in the revision history. [This random question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11782235/item-in-order-to-evaluate-an-indexed-property-the-property-must-be-qualified-a) was just [on my homepage](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QJznZ.png) as bumped by Community, but that is not displayed in [the revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11782235/revisions).

Comment: BTW, before i delete that non-question, could you point me some reference to the meta reputation scoring change that seems to habe been merged with SO? I did not used Meta since a few months and did not noticed that change. The [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/59445) question seems to have been deleted.

Comment: @Seki [Announcing The Launch Of Meta Stack Exchange](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2014/04/announcing-the-launch-of-meta-stack-exchange/)

Comment: @Seki it seems that the feeds don't redirect to MSE. The question is now available at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange

Comment: @Stijn: thanks for the support :)