# User posted a question on MSO 12 hours ago, but their profile says "Last seen February 2018". How is this possible?

Tags: support, profile-page, last-seen

While browsing MSO just now, I stumbled across [this now-deleted question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/391125/3122701). It was a pretty standard "stop downvoting me" rant, but what caught my attention is that while the question itself was posted 12 hours ago (2019-11-07 00:09:00Z), the OP's MSO profile says:

> Last seen Feb 6 '18 at 17:46

This might have been possible if the question had been migrated from Stack Overflow to Meta, but that doesn't seem to be the case here. I'm aware that there can be [minor discrepancies](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255666/3122701) between a user's "last seen" date and when they were *actually* last online, but this is a discrepancy of 21 months.

**What's going on here?**

Comment: Well one explanation would be that the deletion of the question kicked back the last seen date.

Comment: @Gimby I noticed the discrepancy and posted this before the other question was deleted, so that can't be the case either.

Comment: Probably something caching related.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This time, it’s not caching-related.

That question was [originally asked on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58740174/who-are-these-people-on-stack-exchange-yelling-at-new-developers-asking-non-sen) (deleted question: 10k+ only).

It was migrated here to Meta. (It doesn’t show up as being migrated in the revision history because I cleared the migration history after it was migrated.)

Apparently, having a question migrated to a site doesn’t affect your activity on that site.

Comment: Oh, so my suspicion about it being migrated was correct after all. I just didn't realise that migration history could be cleared. Thanks for clearing that up for me!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that was left intentionally, because it's the only way one could know if someone realized their question was migrated and actually followed the path to it.

Comment: "*Apparently, having a question migrated to a site doesn’t affect your activity on that site.*" something that likely crops up very rarely, so it does seem a bit surprising. But upon reflection, sounds correct: it wasn't the *user* who posted the question there, after all.